# How to Find the MIN and MAX for a RDD

Tags: python, pyspark

My RDD is in the below format

```
RDD1=[['2','1','3','4'],['1','2','3','4'],['5','3','4','1']....['1','3','4','5']]
```

or

```
RDD1=[('2','1','3','4'),('1','2','3','4'),('5','3','4','1')....('1','3','4','5')]
```

i want the o/p that finds the min/max across columns as

```
RDD_OUT_MAX=[('5','3','4'...'5')]

RDD_OUT_Min=[('1','1','3'...'1')]
```

how can we achieve by using Pyspark Code,can we use any map/reduce for finding MIN/Max.Please help

```
rdd=df1.rdd.map(list)
rdd=df1.rdd.map(tuple)
```

i have tried below ,but no luck

```
rdd1.min()
rdd1.max()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reduce()` method. Try this:

```
>>> rdd.reduce(lambda x,y:
(min(x[0],y[0]),min(x[1],y[1]),min(x[2],y[2]),min(x[3],y[3])))
(1, 1, 3, 1)
>>> rdd.reduce(lambda x,y: (max(x[0],y[0]),max(x[1],y[1]),max(x[2],y[2]),max(x[3],y[3])))
(5, 3, 4, 5)
```

It does pair-wise min/max checks on each entry of the tuple throughout the rdd.

Slightly shorter but harder to read:

```
>>> rdd.reduce(lambda x,y: tuple(map(min, zip(x,y))))
(1, 1, 3, 1)
>>> rdd.reduce(lambda x,y: tuple(map(max, zip(x,y))))
(5, 3, 4, 5)
```

You can think of it as expanding like this:

```
lambda x,y: tuple(map(max, zip(x,y))) =
lambda x,y: tuple(map(max, [(x[0],y[0]),(x[1],y[1]),(x[2],y[2]),(x[3],y[3])]) =
lambda x,y: tuple([max(x[0],y[0]),max(x[1],y[1]),max(x[2],y[2]),max(x[3],y[3])]) =
lambda x,y: (max(x[0],y[0]),max(x[1],y[1]),max(x[2],y[2]),max(x[3],y[3]))
```

In practice, it uses generators which is why the final `tuple()` is needed.

Comment: Really Thanks,Iam able to calculate Min,but while calculating Max,i am getting below error AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'

Comment: Now able to solve,'NoneType' object has no attribute '_jvm'  also.